# Will the make of wii component cables affect picture quality

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

I'm thinking about getting component video/audio cables for my wii, instead of the existing composite cables (run through a composite to scart adaptor), as I understand I might be able to improve picture quality, but I was wondering if there is a difference in picture quality between different makes of cable, for example between official and third party cables.

The TV is an HD (1080p) PAL TV, if that is relevant.

Comment: If you use an HDMI cable, then it wont make any difference... see here for the explanation http://www.cnet.com/news/why-all-hdmi-cables-are-the-same/

Comment: The wii doesn't support HDMI, so this isn't relevant. The wii doesn't just use a cable, it uses cables (component, composite, S-Video and SCART) that have a custom connector that goes in the wii end.

Comment: As a side note, the WiiU *does* support HDMI and can play Wii games.  Not that I'm suggesting you should upgrade, but it's a thought for the future.

Comment: @Nitro.de. I wouldn't recommend buying the cheapest brandless HDMI cable you can get. I did once and was plagued by signal loss at irregular intervals for 2-10 seconds each. But in general you would be right, there's not much difference (if at all) between different HDMI cable; just be very cautious around suspiciously cheap ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *technically*.

The Wii uses an analog method of sending the image and audio to the TV, analog signals can degrade which decreases the signal quality. Better cables can reduce this.

This does not however mean you should go out and buy the most expensive cable you can find (unless you have money growing on trees, in which case, send me some?) because the difference between a good cable and the best cable is generally very hard to see.

The quality loss is also based on how long the cable is, get a cable that reaches comfortably to the TV with only a bit of slack and don't coil it and you'll get perfectly fine quality.

For example, a test between very expensive audio cables (Monster brand) and... a coat hanger: http://consumerist.com/2008/03/03/do-coat-hangers-sound-as-good-monster-cables/

Comment: Also, the Wii is limited to a highest resolution of 480p so its also not very demanding in terms of component cable quality. If it were pushing out 1080p, the limit of component cable technology, then quality of the cable could make a big difference. With the Wii only outputting low bandwidth video even a relatively poor component cable will be more than good enough.